# ¿como se compara una columna de fechas con una fecha especifica?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, date, select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta imagen del lado izquierdo están las tablas que me dan, del lado 
derecho esta lo que me pide hacer y debajo en azul esta el código que hice

**en lenguaje de base de datos MySQL no se que sentencia se debe utilizar para poder seleccionar datos de una base de datos cuando se requiere comparar con una fecha en especial? yo hice lo de la imagen pero me sale erroneo, cual es la forma correcta?**

[image: esta es la respuesta esperada :'v]

Comment: agrega tu código en forma de texto, así como esta no se distingue

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de lo posible que deje un log de texto y no una imagen del mismo, pues hace mas fácil su lectura para los usuarios, puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre el, y cambiando la imagen por el log de texto. Saludos

Comment: lo tomare en cuenta, gracias por la bienvenida. si se mira borroso el codigo, pero en todo caso ya lo resolvi >u<. gracias de todos modos :3

Comment: DATEDIFF es tu amigo

Comment: :3 ahorita solo me faltan solo unos cuantos más y acabo los códigos yeip

Answer (score 0):

Puedes escribir tu consulta filtrando el año y el mes mediante las funciones `YEAR` y `MONTH` aplicadas a la columna de fecha.

```
SELECT 
    customers.name,
    rentals.rentals_date
FROM customers
    INNER JOIN rentals ON rentals.id_customers=customers.id
WHERE YEAR(rentals.rentals_date) = 2016 AND MONTH(rentals.rentals_date) = 9;
```

Comment: ya lo resolvi, lo que use fue el between para poder hacer un parametro desde el 2016-09-01 al 2016-09-30. y el programa de uri lo acepto, pero muchas gracias :')